# C pointer to pointer

Tags: c

Does

```
int **p
```

and

```
int *p[1]
```

mean the same thing? as both can be passed to functions allowing the change the pointer object, also both can be accessed via p[0], *p ?

**Update,** thanks for your help, tough Memory management seems different. does the access mechanism remain the same

***eg: p[0] becomes *(p+0) & **p (both pointing to something)***

Thanks

Comment: You would access the pointer with `p[0]` not `p[1]`.

Comment: You can use ccdecl to generate documentation that explains pointer declarations like these. http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite.

```
int **p;
```

declares a pointer `p`, which will be used to point at objects of type `int *`, ie, pointers to int.  It doesn't allocate any storage, or point `p` at anything in particular yet.

```
int *p[1];
```

declares an array `p` of one pointer to int: `p`'s type can *decay* to `int **` when it's passed around, but unlike the first statement, `p` here has an initial value and some storage is set aside.

---

Re. the edited question on access syntax: yes, `*p == p[0] == *(p+0)` for all pointers and arrays.

---

Re. the comment asking about `sizeof`: it deals properly with arrays where it can see the declaration, so it gives the total storage size.

```
void foo()
{
    int **ptr;
    int *array[10];

    sizeof(ptr);   // just the size of the pointer
    sizeof(array); // 10 * sizeof(int *)

    // popular idiom for getting count of elements in array:
    sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
}

// this would always discard the array size,
// because the argument always decays to a pointer
size_t my_sizeof(int *p) { return sizeof(p); }
```

Answer (score 4):

To simplify things, you could factor out one level of pointers since it's not relevant to the question.

The question then becomes: what's the difference between `T* t` and `T t[1]`, where `T` is some type.

There are several differences, but the most obvious one has to do with memory management: the latter allocates memory for a single value of type `T`, whereas the the former does not (but it does allocate memory for the pointer).

Comment: thanks, but while accessing the elements, are they internally converted to the same thing, eg: p[0] becomes *(p+0) & *p (both pointing to something) in the first case?

Comment: @Akash: Not entirely sure what you mean by "internally converted", but the machine code for the two cases will almost certainly be different.

Comment: just tried using the size operator, sizeof(**p) and sizeof(*p[1]) both comes as 2, whereas sizeof(*p) and sizeof(p[1]) comes as 2,6 !!!

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same thing, although in many cases they can *appear* to behave the same way.

To make the discussion below flow better, I'm going to take the liberty of renaming your variables:

```
int **pp;   // pointer to pointer
int *ap[1]; // array of pointer
```

If an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" appears in most contexts, it will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" whose value is the address of the first element in the array (the exceptions to this rule are when the array expression is an operand of either the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration).

So, suppose you write something like

```
foo(ap);
```

The expression `ap` has type "1-element array of pointer to `int`", but by the rule above it will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to pointer to `int`"; thus, the function `foo` will receive an argument of type `int **`, not `int *[1]`.

On the other side of the equation, subscripting is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic: `E1[E2]` is defined as `*(E1 + E2)` where one of the expressions is a pointer value and the other is an integral value.  Thus you can use a subscript operator on `pp` *as though* it were an array.  This is why we can treat dynamically-allocated buffers as though they were regular arrays:

```
pp = malloc(sizeof *pp * N); // allocate N pointers to int (type of *pp == int *)
if (pp)
{
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    pp[i] = ...;             // set pp[i] to point to some int value
}
```

Now for some major differences.  First of all, array expressions may not be the target of an assignment; for example, you can't write something like

```
ap = some_new_pointer_value();
```

As mentioned above, array expressions will not be converted to pointer types if they are the operands of either the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators.  Thus, `sizeof ap` tells you the number of bytes required to store a 1-element array of type `int *`, not a pointer to a pointer to `int`.  Similarly, the expression `&ap` has type `int *(*)[1]` (pointer to 1-element array of pointer to `int`), rather than `int ***` (which would be the case for `&pp`).

Comment: Did you mean "allocate N pointers to int *" in the code snippet?

Comment: Nope.  `pp` is an `int **`, meaning it points to something of type `int *`.  Thus each `pp[i]` has type `int *`.

Comment: I believe that `int **` is a pointer to a set of pointers to `int`, i.e. this is like a two-dimensional array of `int`. When you say `pp = malloc(sizeof *pp * N);` you are allocating space for `N` pointers of type `int *` (analogous to `N` rows). For each of `1..N` pointers, you must then allocate space for `M` pointers of type `int` (analogous to `M` columns). I think that the code for the loop you provide will probably crash on the line `pp[i] = ...;` as you do not appear to allocate allocate space for the individual `int *` or `pp[i]` elements.

Comment: That's why the comment reads "set pp[i] to point to some int value"; `pp[i]` would receive a pointer value (either the address of an existing variable or the result of a `malloc` call).  I left that part of the snippet out because it wasn't relevant to the main point (showing how a pointer expression could be subscripted like an array expression).

Comment: Sorry to bug you about this, but the wording seemed unclear to me, as `pp[i]` or `*(pp + i)` is a pointer to an `int *` element, not an `int`. You are dereferencing an `int **`. Perhaps we are saying the same thing, I just wanted to clarify this in my mind.

Comment: The expression `pp` has type `int **`.  The expressions `*pp` and `pp[i]` both have type `int *`.  Thus, `pp[i]` would point to an integer value, as in `pp[i] = &ival;`, where `ival` is an integer variable.  You would access the integer value itself via `*pp[i]` (or `pp[i][0]`).

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same.

- `int **p` is a pointer to a pointer to `int`.
- `int *p[1]` is an array (of length 1) of pointers to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

They are not same:

```
int **p
```

Is a pointer which points to another pointer whose type is `int *`

while,

```
int *p[1];
```

Is an array of size `1` to the type `int *`

Answer (score 1):

They are different.

```
int **p
```

means a pointer to a pointer to an int.

```
int *p[1]
```

means an array containing one element, with that element being a pointer to an int.

The second form can be treated the same as the first in some situations, e.g. by passing it to a function.